# Homebrew で Vim がインストールできない

Tags: vim, homebrew

プログラミングの問題ではないのかもしれませんが…質問させていただければと思います。

Homebrew で Vim をインストールしようとすると
下記のようなエラーが出て、インストールする事が出来ません。

```
$ brew install vim --with-lua
==> Downloading https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v7.4.1589.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-7.4.1589.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1589/share/man --enable-multibyte --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-cscope --with-compiledby=Homebrew --enable-luai
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/akihiroyajima/Library/Logs/Homebrew/vim/02.make:
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -o objects/term.o term.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -o objects/ui.o ui.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -o objects/undo.o undo.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -o objects/window.o window.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -I/usr/local/include -o objects/if_lua.o if_lua.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -g  -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector  -I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE  -o objects/if_perl.o auto/if_perl.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -g  -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector  -I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE  -o objects/if_perlsfio.o if_perlsfio.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME='"/Applications/MAMP/Library"' -fPIE  -o objects/if_python.o if_python.c
if_python.c:67:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/if_python.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [first] Error 2

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Make Install fails for Vim 7.4.1525 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/50197
vim  7.4.488 build fails if Homebrew ruby is installed but /usr/bin/ruby comes first in PATH https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33705
```

エラー文に表示されている issue なども見ながら改善しようと思いましたが、
中々決定打が見つからず…といった感じです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Python.hへのパスが通っていないからではないでしょうか。[このサイト](http://www.yasutomo57jp.com/2011/11/13/mac%E3%81%A7numpy%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/)にはCのコードをコンパイルするのにPython.hが必要と書かれています。

Comment: @zousan `brew install python` で Python をインストールしたところ、インストールできました！ありがとうございました！！

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、ぜひ ご自身で回答を投稿して、その回答に「承認済み」マークをつけてみてください。SOではそれば推奨されていますし、質問が解決済みになるので検索等で来た人にも有益です。

Comment: @take88 ありがとうございます。参考に「承認済み」にさせていただきました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私はanyenvでpyenvを使用しており、同様のエラーに遭遇しました。

以下のコマンドを実行したら成功しました。

```
$ pyenv local system
```

Answer (score 4):

`brew install python` で Python をインストールすると、Vim もインストールできるようになりました！
ご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

自分はbrew install vim --with-luaの時に同じ問題に遭遇しました。

上記内容だけではできなかったので追加します。
pyenvやcondaなどを利用している場合、pythonのパスが変更されることでこのエラーがおきる可能性があるようです。

**自分の解決方法**
1. .bashrcでのPATH変更の部分をコメントアウトし、terminalを再起動
2. brew install vim --with-lua実行 --> 成功
3. .bashrcのコメントアウトを外す